# "High-schooler" vs. "high schooler"

Tags: word-usage, hyphenation, compounds, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

My initial attempt to settle the question with a google search didn't help as much as I'd hoped:

- A search for 'high schooler' revealed approximately **4%** of results employing the hyphenated form.
- A search for 'middle schooler' revealed a significantly higher rate: **20%** of entries employed the hyphenated form. (Including [this recent article](http://www.post-gazette.com/local/city/2014/03/23/And-the-winner-is-1/stories/201403230180).)
- A search for 'elementary schooler' revealed no use of the hyphenated "elementary-schooler" within the first 100 entries. (I stopped looking after that.) So, effectively, **less than 1%**.

Based on this search, it would seem that "middle-schooler" is somewhat acceptable and "elementary-schooler" is not acceptable. "High-schooler", however, is unclear.

What I'm needing to decide right now regards the usage of "high-schooler" which I personally prefer to "high schooler". **Even though google search trends suggest "high schooler" is used much more frequently, can I get away with using the hyphenated form as a stylistic choice?**

My feeling is that if "middle-schooler" is allowed, then "high-schooler" should be just as permissible. After all, someday I might have to type something about a "high high schooler", and I'll wish I had been using the hyphenated form all along.

Comment: Ngram shows about 25% of books used *high-schooler*, and 75% *high schooler*. It is far from unusual; if you want to hyphen it, unless you're following a guide that states differently, i think you should feel free.

Comment: I feel I have to because of the Zite picture, ITS FRONKENSTEEN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran an NGRAM of high schooler, high-schooler, highschooler, high school student, and high-school student.

[Click here to see the results.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=High+schooler%2Chigh-schooler%2Chighschooler%2Chigh+school+student%2C+high-school+student&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CHigh%20schooler%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhigh%20schooler%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHigh%20Schooler%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHigh%20schooler%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chigh%20-%20schooler%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chighschooler%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Chigh%20school%20student%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhigh%20school%20student%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHigh%20School%20Student%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHigh%20School%20student%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHigh%20school%20student%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHIGH%20SCHOOL%20STUDENT%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Chigh%20-%20school%20student%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhigh%20-%20school%20student%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHigh%20-%20School%20Student%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHigh%20-%20school%20student%3B%2Cc0)

By far the preferred nomenclature was high school student.  High schooler was a distant third, and high-schooler barely mapped.  This result was surprising given the rule of hyphenating compound adjectives, but I guess that high school without a hyphen is a standard morphology.

Comment: Thank you and @medica for introducing me to NGRAM. What a game changer!
Even though "high-schooler" barely mapped, it did make up nearly 25% of how the term was spelled.
I'm accepting your answer for the keen observation that no matter how it's spelled, the term should probably be avoided.

Comment: @wordsmitten It is quite useful.  But, it can give spurious results, too.  It doesn't take into account context.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a junior-high school English teacher, and offer my experience at English grammar.  *High school* (no dash) is proper if used alone, such as "I went to *high school*."  However, use a dash if a noun follows the word *school*, as in "a *high-school* boy."  Otherwise, it would read, "a *high school boy*" and would imply that you are talking about a schoolboy who happens to be high (stoned)!  I hope this clears it up.

Oh, one more thing!  Always use a comma before the last item in a list, as in *red, green, and yellow peppers*.  That makes it clear you have *red peppers*, *green peppers*, and *yellow peppers*.  Without that final comma the sentence reads differently: ("*red, green and yellow peppers*"), and one might assume that you have *red peppers* plus some peppers that are *green-and-yellow* (a pepper that has both *green* and *yellow* colors in it).

Write on...!  :)

Comment: The use of the "[Oxford comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma)" is optional: some style guides are in favor of it, and others are against it. So I don't agree that one should "always" use it.

Comment: Never use a dash in the word _high-school_. If it is used attributively, use a **hyphen**. A dash (that is, either an en dash or an em dash) is a different character that has no place inside words. And as sumelic says, using Oxford commas is entirely optional. It also doesn’t really reduce ambiguity: if you say _red, green, and yellow peppers_, one might assume you have yellow peppers as well as the colours red and green. Ambiguity can always be forced if you try hard enough.

Comment: This answer completely ignores the question which is about “high schooler”, not "high-school boy".