# What is the proper usage of "high school" as an adjective?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, orthography

I want to indicate that a friend's brother is in high school. For example,

> I was not close with my friend's high-school brother.

Is this construction correct? Should it be ***high-schooler*** brother instead? Is the hyphen necessary? Or is there another preferred way to say that my friend's brother is in high school?

Comment: I think you have it exactly right, including the hyphen. The only thing I would say is that I would probably replace "with" with "to". These type of questions are best asked on the *English Language Learners* site.

Comment: How can your friend have a "high-school brother"? (It can mean a brother the friend is close with but not necessarily related by blood). I think it would be better parsed: **I was not close with my friend's brother who is in high school.**

Comment: A "high-school brother" would be one who is a brother only in high-school and not at home. You need to say it another way instead.

Comment: OTOH, "high-school students," "high-school teachers," "high-school subjects" are all proper adjective-noun combinations (noun adjunct+noun).

Comment: Related: “High-schooler” vs. “high schooler” https://english.stackexchange.com/q/159462/14666

Comment: @aesking A very large amount of what we say in everyday conversation, and in writing, relies to a greater or lesser extent on context for meaning. Absolute precision would often require interminable sentences, such as "A slight inclination of the cranium is as adequate as the momentary closing of an ovule to an equine devoid of its visionary capacity". (A nod is as good as a wink to a blind horse.)

Comment: @WS2 I disagree that "absolute precision would often require interminable sentences". And my *suggestion* is not about precision, but rather reducing ambiguity. This is so a person is understood in conversation and being efficent with their words. *I'm sure the OP can deduce the correct meaning with their knowledge of context of the situation.*  Anyway, my suggestion for a better parse was not being tautological, tautological is when words can be reduced to a smaller quantity and still retain the same meaning, but mine was about being clear with one's words...

Comment: (cont.) I believe quality is more important than quantity. A simple long sentence such as the parse I suggested can reduce a number of utterances from the hearer trying to deduce the meaning of the sentence. The OP said that they want to empasised the friend's brother is in high school: what better way other than using direct words? If you're familiar with Gricean maxims then you will know what I'm talking about :)

Comment: @aesking I do not altogether disagree with what you say. But the skill is knowing when to make use of context. And I can well imagine a conversation where "my friend's high-school brother" couldn't mean anything other than "my friend's brother who is at high school". If for example it had already been made clear that the friend was a university student.

Comment: Why not just say 'a friend's brother, who is in high school'? Any attempt to compress this, relatively short and perfectly clear, phrase is likely to introduce some unclarity and/or awkwardness.

Answer (score -1):

[high schooler](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/high%20schooler) (M-W)
Here, *high schooler* can be noun adjuct to *brother*:
"I was not close with my friend's high schooler brother."